# Customizer Settings in Arrays

Tags: array, theme-customizer, frontpage

Good afternoon.

I'm using the theme customizer to allow the user to select which pages to show the excerpt of on the front page. I've done this by using an array in the setting name:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'learn_more[0]' , array(
    'default'     => 1
) );
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'learn_more[1]' , array(
    'default'     => 1
) );
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'learn_more[2]' , array(
    'default'     => 1
) );
```

I then create a control for each.

In my `front-page.php` template I then use `get_theme_mod('learn__more')` to provide an array of pages to search for in a custom loop.

It works perfectly. Except...

I've reduced the number of items I want from 4 to 3. But, the 4th item is now stored in the database so each time I use the `get_theme_mod` it returns an array of 4 items. As a result, the loop in my `front-page.php` shows 4 items.

Is there a way to solve this? How can I delete the 4th item in the database? I can see a future position where I will want to adjust the number through a setting on the customizer, but that will cause this problem to happen each time I change the number of items.

Does anyone have any clever ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get_theme_mod()` function works the following:

- It fetches the `get_theme_mods()` function under the hood.
- This returns the following data

  ```
  $theme_slug = get_option( 'stylesheet' );
  get_option( "theme_mods_{$theme_slug}" );
  ```

So in case you upgrade, write an upgrade function specific for that version of your plugin or theme, that uses one of the following, where the name is fetched via `get_option( 'stylesheet' );` again:

- `delete_option( "mods_{$theme_name}" );`
- `update_option( "theme_mods_{$theme_slug}", $mods );`